# How can I use javascript to scroll to the bottom of a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying write a simple chat function page. As the number of lines increases I want the textarea to scroll so that the bottom line is always in view. I have written a  small java script to achieve this following the [W3S example here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp)

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>

    <textarea id="chat-log" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea><br>
    <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="64"><br>
    <input id="chat-message-submit" type="button" value="Send">

    <script>
        var chat_submit = document.getElementById("chat-message-submit");
        chat_submit.onclick = function(e) {
            const messageInputDom = document.getElementById("chat-message-input");
            const message = messageInputDom.value;
            var chat_log = document.getElementById("chat-log");
            messageInputDom.value = '';
            chat_log.value += message + '\n';
            chat_log.scrollIntoView(false); // Bottom
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the chat-log area fills up it does scroll, but it seems to be by only a pixel, and soon the bottom line is lost.

How can I make sure the bottom line is always in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below

```
chat_log.scrollTop = chat_log.scrollHeight;
```